# Runtime Error--java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: provider=gps

Tags: android, gps, locationmanager, illegalargumentexception

I got this error from the user logs on an android app I created. I have been unable to replicate the error thus far. Any help would be extremely appreciated.

The error is:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: provider=gps
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1326)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1276)
at android.location.ILocationManager$Stub$Proxy.requestLocationUpdates(ILocationManager.java:646)
at android.location.LocationManager._requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.java:582)
at android.location.LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.java:446)
at com.myApp.service.DeviceManager$7.handleMessage(DeviceManager.java:470)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3835)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:883)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:641)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The devicemanager location it refers to is:

```
private final Handler uihandler = new Handler() {

 @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
                case MSG_TOAST:
                    Toast.makeText(DeviceManager.this, msg.arg1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;

                case MSG_ENABLE_LOCATION:
                    mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 60000, 1,DeviceManager.this);
                   mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                            60000, 1, DeviceManager.this);
                    break;

                case MSG_DISABLE_LOCATION:
                    mLocationManager.removeUpdates(DeviceManager.this);
                    break;

                case MSG_STOP_SELF:
                    break;
            }
        }

    };
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sorry forgot to post the solution. The problem ended up being due to a user force closing the app in the middle of a location update. Nothing we can do about that!

Comment: mLocationManager.removeUpdates in onPause didn't work?  Things should never crash when closing apps...

Answer (score 1):

`IllegalArgumentException`  if provider is null or doesn't exist. Make sure GPS provider enabled.

Did you check this [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html)? Have you added following entry manifest file?

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Comment: Yes thank you I had already included that in the manifest. I put ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION since it covers both network and GPS permissions in one. What do you mean by "make sure GPS provider enabled"? thanks!

Comment: Enable GPS on your phone if it is not enabled.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it can run without GPS enabled since we have LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER enabled as well. Thanks for the response. Do you have any other ideas what could be causing it? I got the error from one of our users so I'm just trying to figure out what could have caused it.

Comment: I agree NETWORK_PROVIDER works. see if this link can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8871825/error-handling-in-android-exception-caused-by-java-lang-illegalargumentexcepti

Comment: Yeah i studied that for awhile before even posting a question. Do you think this error could be particular to a certain type of phone/android OS?

Comment: No i've been unable to reproduce it so far

Comment: I strongly suspect none of the providers were enabled on your customer phone. You may try to reproduce on your end by disabling NETWORK_PROVIDER and GPS_PROVIDER. I am positive that you will get this error.

Comment: Do you mean by disabling the permissions? Or how exactly would i go about doing that? Thanks so much for the input!

Comment: Do you have any additional insight??